# in Windows Phone 8 I need when iam in the range of 1km from a specific point i see a toast notification

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary, windows-phone, toast, here-api

I need in WP 8 when a device be in the range of specific point (say 1km range) the application shown a toast notification tell me that am near this place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix a set of coordinates, latitude and longitude which is your specific point.
You have the position changed event for the geolocator which you can handle.

like here:: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx

Once you have that working, you can calculate distance between two locations as shown here,

[Calculating Distance between two Latitude and Longitude GeoCoordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366408/calculating-distance-between-two-latitude-and-longitude-geocoordinates)

And you can show any pop up on the screen if you find that the distance is greater than or equal to 1km. 
Hope that helps.