# how to get a distance between my current location to every found nearby location using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a small application to search a nearby location from current location using xamarin forms in visual studio 2017. I am having list of company address in sqlite, For examble I type something like "Perungudi" in the Entry box then the listview filled with the list of matched nearby query "Perungudi", Which is record coming from sqlite, My question is "how to get a distance between my current location to every found nearby location" (distance like 1 km or 2 km and Company name), Please give me suggestion to resolve this issue so that i can search right way

Comment: You can find your solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366408/calculating-distance-between-two-latitude-and-longitude-geocoordinates

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your SQLite records include a location, you can use **CalculateDistance** from **Xamarin.Essentials** to obtain the value. This is an extension method, you can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.locationextensions.calculatedistance.

The following should help you understand the approach:

```cs
// Your DB Model
class SavedLocation
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Class for binding in the ListView
class LocationWithDistance
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Distance { get; set; }
}

class SomeViewModel
{
    public IList<LocationWithDistance> FetchNearbyLocations(string name)
    {
        var currentLocation = new Location(19, -99); // This is your current location
        var sqliteData = new List<SavedLocation>(); // Data you get from SQLite

        var itemsForListView = from item in sqliteData
                               select new LocationWithDistance
                               {
                                   Name = item.Name,
                                   Distance = new Location(item.Latitude, item.Longitude).CalculateDistance(currentLocation, DistanceUnits.Kilometers)
                               };

        return itemsForListView.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, This is what i want,  i am working on it, if i have any doubt, let you know

Comment: HI Juan. I have one doubt, About the calculating by latlng is just about the distance likewise I need Driving Distance

Comment: For that you will need to use a 3rd party service. Google's Distance Matrix API does exactly that. You can specify which Travel Mode you want: driving (default), walking, bicycling or transit. Please look here for details: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#travel_modes