# Find distance between 2 coordinates in .NET core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, geolocation, geospatial

I need to find the distance between 2 coordinates in .NET core. I've tried using the below mentioned code,

```cs
var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(sLatitude, sLongitude);
var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(eLatitude, eLongitude);

return sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);
```

But, it seems like the GeoCoordinate class is not supported in .NET core. Is there any other precise way to calculate the distance between 2 coordinates using the latitude and longitude in .NET core?

Comment: GeoCoordinate class is part of System.Device.dll and that too in, net framework.

Comment: This answer provides a standalone solution without System.Device.dll https://stackoverflow.com/a/24712129/5519026

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GeoCoordinate class is part of System.Device.dll in .net framework. But, it is not supported in .Net Core. I have found alternative methods to find the distance between 2 coordinates.

```
    public double CalculateDistance(Location point1, Location point2)
    {
        var d1 = point1.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        var num1 = point1.Longitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        var d2 = point2.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        var num2 = point2.Longitude * (Math.PI / 180.0) - num1;
        var d3 = Math.Pow(Math.Sin((d2 - d1) / 2.0), 2.0) +
                 Math.Cos(d1) * Math.Cos(d2) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num2 / 2.0), 2.0);
        return 6376500.0 * (2.0 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(d3), Math.Sqrt(1.0 - d3)));
    }
```

where point1 and point2 are 2 points with the coordinates and Location is a class as shown below,

```
public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Please check the link for another method to calculate the distance, which gives the same result as the above code -
[Alternative method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502821/13013258)

Comment: For reference, the above method returns the distance in meters. Also, if you're able to leverage multi-targeting in your project, Microsoft has a .Net Core GeoLocation NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geolocation.NetStandard/

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer.  Seems other solutions involve complicated projections.  This was easy to use.

Comment: In 2022, this original Geolocation nuget package seems to be compatible with .NET core - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geolocation/

Comment: Is this really a Nuget published by Microsoft? I see an individual's name as the author.  I would love to see Microsoft itself publish one

Comment: As an alternative to the other libraries recommended, you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeoCoordinate.NetCore as a .Net Core replacement for the .Net framework GeoCoordinate.