# Why Calculating Distance Between Two Coordinates using Latitude and Longitude Takes More time?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am working on one requirement in which i need to show only those records which falls inside the radius from circle.
For this i am using .net core as backend api using entity framework core. I am first fetching all records and after that calculating distance based on records from database and my runtime latitude and longitude.
I have used below link and implemented the code to calculate distance.
[find-distance-between-2-coordinates-in-net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700865/find-distance-between-2-coordinates-in-net-core)
Everything works well in localhost, but when i deploy these changes in server it fails.

It takes more time as there are more than 50 records to process and calculate distance one by one.
Also while debugging i found that CalculateDistance takes almost 3-4 seconds per record for calculating distance and giving them in 'kms'

Can anyone please throw some light on this as i am stuck in this issue since more than 2 days.

```
private static double DistanceTo(double lat1, double lon1, double? lat2, double? lon2, char unit = 'K')
{
    double rlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
    double rlat2 = (double)(Math.PI * lat2 / 180);
    double theta = (double)(lon1 - lon2);
    double rtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
    double dist =
        Math.Sin(rlat1) * Math.Sin(rlat2) + Math.Cos(rlat1) *
        Math.Cos(rlat2) * Math.Cos(rtheta);
    dist = Math.Acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

    switch (unit)
    {
        case 'K': //Kilometers -> default
            return dist * 1.609344;
        case 'N': //Nautical Miles 
            return dist * 0.8684;
        case 'M': //Miles
            return dist;
    }

    return dist;
}
```

//Some more code from were this function is getting called

```
    foreach (var objList in objPaginatedList)
{
    if (DistanceTo(objList.Latitude, objList.Longitude, offeredServiceSubCategoriesAreasCovered.First().Latitude!,
        offeredServiceSubCategoriesAreasCovered.First().Longitude!, 'K') < Convert.ToDouble(radiusFromCircle.First().DistanceInKiloMeters!.Split(" km")[0]))
    {
        obj!.Add(new GetEstimateRequestsAsPerSupplierOfferedServiceAndLocationDto
        {
            CategoryName = objList.CategoryName,
            CityName = objList.CityName,
            CountryName = objList.CountryName,
            Created = objList.Created,
            CreatedBy = objList.CreatedBy,
            EstimateRequestRecordId = objList.EstimateRequestRecordId,
            EstimateRequests = objList.EstimateRequests,
            EstimateRequestsId = objList.EstimateRequestsId,
            IsActive = objList.IsActive,
            LastModified = objList.LastModified,
            LastModifiedBy = objList.LastModifiedBy,
            Latitude = objList.Latitude,
            Longitude = objList.Longitude,
            LineItemCategoryId = objList.LineItemCategoryId,
            PlaceId = objList.PlaceId,
            ProjectName = objList.ProjectName,
            LineItemSubCategoryRecordId = objList.LineItemSubCategoryRecordId,
            StateName = objList.StateName,
            StreetAddressLine1 = objList.StreetAddressLine1,
            SubCategoryName = objList.SubCategoryName
        });
    }
}
```

}

So the above function will get called 50 times if there are 50 records

Comment: If your database supports spatial data types, push the query logic down to the database, where indexes may be used and avoid doing this work in the application. E.g. in SQL Server you'd want to use [`STDistance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16) in your query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for your response. Appreciated. I am using .net core using entityframework core.

Comment: You can write raw sql with entity framework (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries).

Comment: Well, if it is better pushed to the db is one thing. The other is that a single distance Calc  taking 3-4 seconds seems ridiculously much to me. If you share the implementation, we maybe can see what's wrong with that. Does it at least give you _correct_ results?

Comment: @Fildor thank you for your response. Yes it does gives me correct response. I have edited the question and added the code snippet above. You can please have a look

Comment: No, please include the code *in the question directly*. Questions should stand alone, without us having to go to a different page.

Comment: code added sorry took a while for me to format

Comment: I doubt your haversine function itself takes '3-4 seconds per record' to execute. Can you show some more code that depicts how your function is called/used?

Comment: Also the formula seems to not to be implemented correctly.

Comment: I have added more code snippet

Comment: Executing your function contineously takes less than one millisecond on my (absolutely average) machine. There must be something else going on in your code

Comment: Done thank you so much all. My mistake was that i was getting the .First() linQ method to get the first record everytime. So just removed it from there as there were lots of inner queries as well which were taking a lot of time to get execute